# Mockito shows IllegalStateException in Android Studio

Tags: android, mockito

I am not able to mock object inside my unit test.

**Code Snippet:**

```
@Before
public void setUp(){
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}

@Test
public void test_employee_name() {
    Employee employee = Mockito.mock(Employee.class);
    when(employee.getName())
            .thenReturn("jitesh");
    assertEquals("jitesh", employee.getName());
}
```

**Dependencies:**

```
testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.7.22'
```

**Gradle:**

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
    testOptions {
        unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    // Room components
    implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.1"
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.1"
    androidTestImplementation "android.arch.persistence.room:testing:1.1.1"
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.1.1"
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1"

    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.7.22' 
}
```

**Error:**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not initialize plugin: interface org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.PluginLoader$1.invoke(PluginLoader.java:66)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy7.isTypeMockable(Unknown Source)
    at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.typeMockabilityOf(MockUtil.java:29)
    at org.mockito.internal.util.MockCreationValidator.validateType(MockCreationValidator.java:22)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.MockSettingsImpl.validatedSettings(MockSettingsImpl.java:186)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.MockSettingsImpl.confirm(MockSettingsImpl.java:180)
    at org.mockito.internal.MockitoCore.mock(MockitoCore.java:62)
    at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1729)
    at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1642)
    at com.example.myapplication.ExampleUnitTest.setUp(ExampleUnitTest.java:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/bytebuddy/dynamic/loading/ClassLoadingStrategy
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.SubclassByteBuddyMockMaker.<init>(SubclassByteBuddyMockMaker.java:33)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyMockMaker.<init>(ByteBuddyMockMaker.java:21)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.PluginLoader.loadPlugin(PluginLoader.java:54)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.PluginRegistry.<init>(PluginRegistry.java:18)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.Plugins.<clinit>(Plugins.java:17)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.GlobalConfiguration.tryGetPluginAnnotationEngine(GlobalConfiguration.java:55)
    at org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(MockitoAnnotations.java:68)
    at com.example.myapplication.ExampleUnitTest.setUp(ExampleUnitTest.java:29)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassLoadingStrategy
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

Comment: Can you add the full stacktrace?

Comment: @second: Please have a look.

Comment: Do you use `roboelectrics`? You also might want to have a look at [`this`](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/1017)

Comment: @second: I am not using roboelectrics.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that you used gradle. But anyway `ClassNotFound` Errors are indicating that you have a problem with your classpath or the build tools you use. So figure out why the related depedency is not available.

Comment: Please add your `build.gradle` to the post.

Comment: @ErnestZamelczyk: Please have a look at gradle

Comment: Actually what java vm (version / vendor)  are you using and did you enable final mocking, like `@ZaferCelaloglu` suggested? While I don't think this will solve your issue I coincidental stumpled about the last note of point 39 in the [`faq`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.0.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#Mocking_Final). If you are using a `non-JDK VM prior to Java 9` that might explain why the `bytebuddy` classes are not there.

Comment: @jitsm555 can you paste your complete unit test class including import statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what exactly goes wrong here, after clean and make the project everything seems to get working.

It seems that some other dependencies causing this issue If anyone facing the same issue in the future, just try to create a sample of it first and then only do implement inside your project.

Answer (score 2):

Works for me in a simple Java project, so it might be a problem in your environment. Here is my minimal working example:

Productive class:

```
public class Employee {

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Test class:

```
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

public class FooTest {
    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void test_employee_name() {
        Employee employee = Mockito.mock(Employee.class);
        when(employee.getName())
                .thenReturn("jitesh");
        assertEquals("jitesh", employee.getName());
    }
}
```

Dependencies in pom:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.22</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Can you please help me to run it in your android studio. I am more concerned about why this error coming.

Comment: I do not have android studio available, so unfortunately I cannot. I suggest you setup a minimal working example project in your android studio using the code I posted in my answer. If that works, the reason is not android studio but something different you use in your project. If it does not work, we narrowed the error space down to android studio.

Answer (score 0):

add `org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker` file under the test package

you can check out my [GitHub](https://github.com/Zfr21/WeatherLogger/blob/master/app/src/test/resources/mockito-extensions/org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker) repository

Comment: Can you elaborate how and why this should resolve the `ClassNotFound` error?

Answer (score 0):

Zafers answer is correct. You need to have a file under `app/src/main/resources/mockito-extensions` called `org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker` with just this line inside `mock-maker-inline`.

As you can see in the [documentation](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/What%27s-new-in-Mockito-2#mock-the-unmockable-opt-in-mocking-of-final-classesmethods), you need that in order to mock final classes.

Comment: Your question looks more like a comment to me (as you point out something in regard to Zafers answer). If you wanted to improve his answer you should have submitted an edit or have left a comment there.

Comment: As you say that his answer is correct, maybe you can add some more details about the issue why and how mocking a `final` class is related to the `ClassNotFound` Error?

Comment: Agree to @second please improve my answer or just delete your duplicate answer

Answer (score -1):

Seems like you might have forgotten to annotate your test class with `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner::class)`